# Validate string using regular expression

Tags: regex

We need to validate comma delimited strings using regular expressions with specific validation rules:

1. apart from alphanumeric values, only allowed tokens are comma, colon, space and hyphen
2. if we have a colon (:) in the sub string:

   - length of string on both sides should match.
   - Position of space or hyphen(only those are allowed) on both side should also match.
   - string on both sides cannot begin/end with - or space.

Here is an example of a valid string:

```
asd asds:121 asdd,qrt-123:rwt-wqe,ADER*,AASD
```

Valid ones:

- 100a
- 100test*
- 100a,100a,100a*
- 100-1000:300-ASDS
- asd asds:121 asdd,qrt-123:rwt-wqe

Invalids are:

- 100a*w
- 100-10:10-10
- sep j:se pj
- 100-10:100-10,ABC DER:AB CD

This is what we've tried so far, but it only takes care of the basics:

```
[0-9a-zA-Z\-:\* ]{1,20}([,|\n|\r][0-9a-zA-Z\-:\* ]{1,20})*
```

I'm new to the world of regular expressions, can you please help me build one for this?

Comment: Rather than giving random examples what are the _rules_ for your `String`? What regex engine are you using?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just asking for code without showing any prior own efforts.

Comment: I have updated the question with the exact problem statement and my efforts.Please answer..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> - length of string on both sides should match
> - Position of space or hyphen(only those are allowed) on both side should also match.

You can't do this with a Regex. Consider writing a simple state machine parser to achieve your goal. It'd also be more maintainable that way.

Comment: Thank you.We written java-script function to achieve this..Thank you so much for the help.